# How to deserialize this dictionary-like XML to Dictionary<string, TValue>?

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, generics, serialization

I have the following `materials.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<dictionary>
  <Sand>
    <id>1000</id>
    <name>Sand</name>
    <state>Dust</state>
    <color>#FAFAFAFF</color>
  </Sand>
  <Water>
    <id>2000</id>
    <name>Water</name>
    <color>#1CA3EC64</color>
    <state>Liquid</state>
  </Water>
  <Gas>
    <color>#5F6A0032</color>
    <id>3000</id>
    <name>Gas</name>
    <state>Gas</state>
  </Gas>
</dictionary>
```

A single material is represented with the following class:

```cs
public class Material {
  public readonly int id;
  public readonly string name;
  public Color color;
  public MaterialState state;
}
```

I need a generic `SerializableDictionary` class that can be used like this:

```cs
var materials = new SerializableDictionary<Material>();
//...serialization stuff
materials["Rock"].color;
```

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            
            List<Material> materials = doc.Root.Elements()
                .Select(x => new Material()
                {
                    id = (int)x.Element("id"),
                    name = (string)x.Element("name"),
                    color =  Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(((string)x.Element("color")).Substring(1), NumberStyles.HexNumber)),
                    state = (MaterialState)Enum.Parse(typeof(MaterialState),(string)x.Element("state"))
                }).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, Material> dict = materials
                .GroupBy(x => x.name, y => y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

        }
    }
    public enum MaterialState
    {
        Dust,
        Liquid,
        Gas
    }
    public class Material
    {
        public int id { get;set; }
        public string name { get;set;}
        public Color color { get;set;}
        public MaterialState state { get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, this is useful but I thought I could achieve this with a generic class that converts the contents of each element in `<dictionary>` to `Material`. Maybe replacing `<Sand>`, `<Water>`, `<Gas>` elements with for example `<item>`element could help generalize serialization logic? I tried to use `XmlReader` for this purpose but seems like it can't convert contents of an element to a class (or most likely I did something wrong).

Comment: I think you would need a base class Material with inherited classes Sand, Water, Gas.  It doesn't matter if you parse the file with XmlReader or Xml Linq you would still need the three inherited classes.